# I am getting an error when using class components in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When I create a class component in Gatsby, I receive the error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

The code goes as follows:

**Slider.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'gatsby'


export default class Slider extends React.component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {/* <Slide /> */}
                <div>
                    <h1>The New lorem</h1>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum </p>
                    <Link>View Lorem</Link>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: you meant `React.Component ` capital `C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant `React.Component` capital `C`

```
export default class Slider extends React.Component {...}
```

Comment: Embarassing or not, your question just saved my butt.  Thank you!